# PHP S3 - How to get all versions of a specific file

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Laravel project and a version enabled S3 bucket. I can list the versions of all objects within the bucket using the `listObjectVersions` method.

My attempt to list the versions of a specific object is as follows:

```
     $result = $client->listObjectVersions([
            'Bucket' => \Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Key' => $folder . '/' . 'test.png',
        ]);
```

This seems to get all objects within the bucket which is not what I want. Is there a way to get just one file?

I am using the AWS PHP SDK.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to loop through the ObjectVersions and then download each individual Version one-at-a-time.

Comment: Thanks. I would have thought this would be a common use case, but maybe there is a good reason to delegate the responsibility to the consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Prefix' instead of 'Key':

```
        $client = new S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'eu-west-1'
        ]);

        $folder = $this->getS3Folder($request, $study);

        $result = $client->listObjectVersions([
            'Bucket' => \Config::get('filesystems.disks.s3.bucket'),
            'Prefix' => $folder . '/' . 'test.png',
        ]);
```